# UISearchController wrong position because of with tableview inset

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uikit

I'm working on a feature that has custom view above UITableView, it looks like TableView has contentInset. I added SearchController to a TableViewHeader, but when I tap on searchTextView SearchController moves up with animation (about 20px). I want that UISearchBar will be at the top of ViewController like in "Constacts"

**This screenshot shows how it's now:**

[image]

**this one is how I want:**

[image]

What should i do? I need contentInset after searching (user tapped on cancel), but during the searching I do not need it.

I want to provide app example, that demonstrates all this stuff -> [enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzsxcvnBqFM7QjBTamtQMXR5dHM)

Comment: I assume it's something related to your constraints, but just to make sure it isn't something simpler, did you make sure to set `self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false` on the view controller? That flag usually leaves some unwanted gaps above table views.

Comment: The main problem is - when you set custom insets default animation of UISearchViewController not working. automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets wouldn't help

Comment: Even i feel thats constraint issue. Are you giving constant top constraint for the tableView?

Comment: @NosovPavel Please check my answer

Answer (score 7):

**If you are using storyboards** You should click on the view controller or TableView Controller which you have set up for your tableview and go to its attribute inspector and look under ViewController section and check the Extend Edges section to be under Top Bars.

```
                      **OR**
```

Check both Under Top Bars and Under Opaque Bars and leave Under Bottom Bars unchecked.

**Do this :**

[image: option 1]

**OR**
**DO this :**

[image: option2]

Comment: The second option "Check Under Opaque Bars" solved my problem where the searchbar move downward when keyboard appears, thanks!

Comment: I think you sent to the wrong guy, I'm not the OP :-)

Answer (score 5):

Try playing with `Adjust Scroll View Insets`, `Under Top Bars`, and `Under Bottom Bars` in the interface builder. I had the same issue with a collectionView and toggling them off worked for me. You example project works for me but when I toggle between those settings it breaks.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Add the code below to `viewWillAppear()`

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

Comment: 'automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets' was deprecated in iOS 11.0: Use UIScrollView's contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior instead

Comment: Thanks, You saved my time.!

Answer (score 1):

How about adjust content inset each time once searchBar is triggered to begin/end editing:

```
// MARK: - UISearchBarDelegate
func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {
    UIView.transition(with: self.tableView,
                      duration: 0.6,
                      options: .curveLinear,
                      animations: {
                        self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero
    }, completion: { success in })
    return true
}

func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    UIView.transition(with: self.tableView,
                      duration: 0.6,
                      options: .curveLinear,
                      animations: {
                        self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 100, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
    }, completion: { success in })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a temporary UISearchBar and assign it as a tableHeaderView

   ```
   searchbar   =   UISearchBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 375, height: 44))
   searchbar?.delegate =   self
   tableView.tableHeaderView = searchbar
   ```
2. and before the tap of the searchBar present the UISearchController to replicate the animation

   ```
   func searchBarShouldBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) -> Bool {

       if searchBar == searchbar {

          self.tableView.tableHeaderView  =   nil

          UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.33, animations: {
              // 64+44 is due because the navigation gets hidden and also because of the temp searchBar as tableHeaderView
              self.tableView.contentInset =   UIEdgeInsets(top: 64+44, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
          }, completion: { _ in

          })
          self.present(searchController, animated: true, completion: nil)
      }

      return false

   }
   ```
3. And finally on cancel button of UISearchController searchBar reset the tableView contentInset

   ```
   func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
       if searchBar == searchController.searchBar {
           UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.33, animations: {
               self.tableView.contentInset =   UIEdgeInsets(top: 100+44, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
           }, completion: { _ in

           })

           self.searchbar?.isHidden    =   false
           self.tableView.tableHeaderView  =   self.searchbar
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I have had the same issue with the UISearchBar attached in a UIViewController, below the search bar is an UICollectionView, so the bug report was if I scroll down the listing (UICollectionView) the scrollview will be automatically adjusted by default by the OS.

We can disable the behavior like this, typically in a view setup function under viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear:

```swift
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            self.collectionView.contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior = .never
        } else {
            automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
        }
```

reference:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/44880387/1477298
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscrollview/contentinsetadjustmentbehavior
- https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621372-automaticallyadjustsscrollviewin#

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue I fixed it by setting `edgesForExtendedLayout` to none,
but after researching as well the solution may vary depends on your implementation of your hierarchy you may want to uncheck `Extend Edges Under Top Bar` from storyboard.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I tried to do it. Please see my comment above

Answer (score 0):

Well first, I looked at both the projects you linked and in the Objective-C version there is no content inset, it's just a normal table view.

As for your problem, let me make sure I understand. Here is what you need:

1. Table view
2. Picture above that table view that doesn't change position, doesn't scroll, simply stays up there
3. Search bar that at the top of the table, but below the fixed image
4. When user is searching, hide the picture and bring the table view all the way up
5. When user is done searching, you want the table to come down so that the image can be displayed at the top again

Right?

Assuming this is true, here is my idea.

First of all, I would ditch `UITableViewController` and change it to just `UIViewController`. Add the table view as a subview and manage its position from the view controller. This means that you don't mess around with content insets, you just place the table below the image and that's it. I am not sure if you want the search bar above the image or below, but assuming it is below, still just keep it as a header to the table view and when it becomes active, simply animate table view and image to move up until image is gone and the table view is at the top. If you want the search bar to be above the image then don't add it to the table view but rather add it as a subview of the main view, separate of everything, and manage it's position through code rather than letting the OS handle it. Also, there might be an issue with the search controller, I haven't used it much so I am not sure, but you may be better off just using a `UISearchBar` and handling all the searching yourself.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

**I think your YourVC(VC which have SearchBar and Table View) are embeded in NavigationController or just pushed by VC which is embeded.**

Please have a look to this [Sample](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B_wq4FyWzrQVMGdjcDR3VmJCX00), I have created for you.

Note:

1. Put CustomView Height Constraint(Top:0,Leading:0,trailing:0,Height:60).
2. Put Search Bar in custom view, add Constraint on search Bar as (Top:20,leading:0,trailing:0,bottom:0).
3. Use Minimal SearchBarStyle for searchBar.
4. Enable Cancel button in search Bar.
5. Give background color to the custom view same as the color of Search Bar by using Color Picker.
6. Put TableView Below the customView and give constraint as (vertical spacing to custom view:0, leading:0,trailing:0,bottom:0).
7. Uncheck the "Adjust scroll View Insets", as like i have shown in image below.[image: Uncheck the "Adjust scroll View Insets"]

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: No, it's no helpful because it's not what i'm searching for. Your Sample did't work as I expected. There is no default animation of searchBar and also there is no insets

Answer (score 0):

Actually the view controller is trying to adjust content insets of your `UITableView` equal to navigation bar height automatically.

Unchecking the `Adjust Scroll View Insets` should fix your problem. I also had this issue while using storyboards.

Answer (score 0):

It seem's you trying to adjust tableView inside ViewController, if is that the case you can fix it by just adding empty view over your tableView object and under navigationBar in storyboard and give it constraints like this.

[image: storyBoard]

I know this is some kind of hackie but this will solve your problem, to implement the searchController i use this in my project and it is work fine

```
var searchController: UISearchController?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    searchController?.isActive = true
    searchController = initSearchController()
}

func initSearchController() -> UISearchController {
    let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    searchController.searchBar.delegate = self
    searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = true
    searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    definesPresentationContext = true


    searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
    searchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = searchController.searchBar
    tableView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 
    searchController.searchBar.frame.size.height)
    return searchController
}
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are using a navigation controller, which introduces a navigationBar above the tableView. So u need to do 2 things.

1. hide the navigationBar using,

   self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = YES;//(objective c)
    self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden = true;//(swift)
2. adjust the frame of the tableview, by changing its origin.y from 0 to -44(since height of navigationBar is 44) as shown below,
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

I just set `self.extendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars` as true solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

you have to use This code Below:

```
navigationItem.searchController = YourSeachController
```